# How to relocate to another page when the user refreshes the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to have the following functionality. When the user refreshes the page I want it to go to a certain page Eg:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload',function(){

     window.location.href = "#splash";

});
```

Now the .bind() works because if I say `return 'Really?';` it opens up a dialog saying Really? But I would like the page to be changed. How would I do this?

Comment: You can not control the page location when it exits. Why don't you set a localstorage value when check that on page render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found next tip (tested in latest chrome):

```
var flag = true;
function confirmExit()
{
if (flag)
 setTimeout(function(){flag=false;location = '/index.html';});
}
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload',function(e){

     e.preventDefault();    
     window.location.href = "#splash";

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
function confirmExit()
{
 alert("exiting");
 window.location.href='index.html';
 return true;
}
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
```

Comment: No such luck with this answer. I'm using jquery mobile. I don't know if that is the problem